# I have messed up my question what should I do now?

Tags: support

I have asked question recently in Arduino Stack exchange but I forgot to specify the problem clearly. I thought it is a problem with the Arduino's `serial.read()`. Seems like the question belongs to Super User or Electrical stack exchange. What should I do?

I was going to delete the question but the question has answers now but the answers did not help. I see this question more into Serial communication. Also I have seen many users having the kind of same problem in reddit and Arduino forums.

The question may not have a answer at all, it may be old devices (Versastat II) are not compatible with modern devices. I have fully edited the question after the two answers, which is bad indeed, afterwards added the full problem scenario..

Should I delete the question and repost? Help!

Thank you

Question

[How to read incoming HEX values from Serial.read() method?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/81526/how-to-read-incoming-hex-values-from-serial-read-method?noredirect=1#comment183094_81526)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the question has answers now but the answers did not help

Your question is detailed, and the answers seem to be trying to help you.

I don't think deleting the question will help. I suggest trying to work with the people that are answering you and try to work your way to a solution.

> seems like the question belongs to Super User or Electrical stack exchange

Certainly not Super User. I think you should stay here and work out the issue.

Answer (score 2):

If your question has changed, it is better to leave the original question as is and ask a new question. That way the answers to the original question stay relevant.